# What Types of Glass Are Used with Flatbed Scanners? (And are there good scratch-resistant options?)

Tags: scanner

So, I'm actually really surprised that I can't find anything on Google about this subject, so maybe I'm asking the wrong questions or maybe there really just isn't a lot of information out there on this subject, but I need to know if there are different varieties of glass that can be purchased for an Epson DS-50000 flatbed scanner, and what they are if there are variations.

Specifically, I am looking for something a bit more scratch resistant than the standard glass that comes with the scanner.  The company I work for scans hundreds of slabbed comic books a day and I was looking to see if there was a type of glass we could order that would hold up to the hard plastic a bit longer before needing to be replaced.  I'm just a programmer.  I don't know how all these physical bits and bobs actually work.  Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to contact Epson about this? It seems like a question that only a trained Epson support/sales employee could answer for your specific model. Ordering replacement panes of glass for that scanner is probably only possible through them anyways. Generally speaking, there is a variety of scratch-resistant glasses that *could* be used, but I don't expect there to be much of a third-party market for glass replacement on scanners.

Comment: Would putting a clear plastic transparency over the glass help?  For example:  https://www.amazon.com/KOALA-Film-Laser-Printer-Sheets/dp/B07KP1G6DV/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?keywords=transparency+overhead+projector+scratch+resistant&qid=1580764334&sr=8-1-fkmr1  I am not recommending this specific product, just a clear sheet of plastic on top of  the glass.

Comment: There are sprays for glass to make them more scratch resistant.  Or if you are daring, find a supplier of scratch resistant glass, take off the glass from the scanner, get it replicated and put it back in.  They will need it  as a template to cut the new piece and thickness is going to be important.

Answer (score 0):

A review of Epson's [European](https://www.epson.eu/products/scanners/business-scanners/workforce-ds-50000/Support-Downloads) and [US](https://epson.com/Support/Scanners/WorkForce-Series/Epson-WorkForce-DS-50000/s/SPT_B11B204121#manuals) documentation for that scanner showed no hardware manual, and no specification for the thickness, width, or length of any glass replacement for that plastic window.

Checking their [list of distributors](https://epson.com/Support/wa00399) led me to https://compassmicro.com/media/wysiwyg/diagrams/DS-50000-exploded-diag.pdf which shows item 124 is the scanning window and is replaceable. If you contact Compass Micro Support at (360) 836-8122, Mon - Fri, 8AM - 4:30PM Pacific Time, they can assist you with obtaining a replacement.

Until then, keep the scanning window clean to minimize the chance of a scratch.